# Как заполнить массив в классе модели выборкой из базы на PHP

Tags: php, база-данных, pdo

Имеется класс Price в нем происходит обращение к базе через PDO и полученные данные возвращаются return  в контроллер. В итоге в контроллере при вызове Price, получении результата и выводе на foreach получаем 1 строку, так как запрос по умолчанию возвращает одну строку. Как в модели реализовать заполнение массива полностью данными из базы, и потом уже понятно скорее всего return поскольку массив отдать данные на контроллер и там уже вывести на foreach

Comment: если у вас имеется класс, то приведите его код, иначе обсуждать тут нечего

Comment: А у вас точно все записи извлекаются(fetchAll)? Или может быть в запросе LIMIT стотит?

Comment: частая ошибка это не указание фигурных скобок при заполнении массива проверьте чтобы у вас стояли скобки `$var[] = $var->fetchAll()`

Comment: Лимита нет $sth уже содержит подключения, вот код while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {echo $row['title']; echo $row['description']; // В итоге получаем нормальный вывод, но код нужно писать сразу в контроллере, а нужно в модели, а потом отдать массив, полученный в модели в контроллер, что-то подобное $model = array(); while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { $model = и как-то эту переменную наполняем выводом из базы, и вот вопрос как? Спасибо всем кто ответил, и всем кто еще ответит